# Google Maps Flyover Slideshow

Tags: maps, slideshow

I'd like to create some sort of a slideshow on a website where you can jump to predefined points on the globe by clicking next and prev buttons. Something similar to this: http://developmentseed.org/ Is it possible to create this with an embed google map? Or does anybody know another solution for this?